# evercookie in Spring Security rememberme-service

Tags: cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I'd like to use the evercookie javascript library to receive the users cookie and make the spring security rememberme-service use it.

I read a bit about implementing a custom remember-me service, but I think I just need to discover the cookie on the client-side using the evercookie library. I've got zero knowledge about cookie handling, so any help how to implement the evercookie library so that a cookie will be set and discovered through the library would be appreciated.

evercookie: [samy.pl](http://samy.pl/evercookie/)

Comment: "I've got zero knowledge about cookie handling" and "I'd like to use the evercookie javascript library" in one question sound like a recipe for disaster. Why do you think you need this particular piece of software?

Comment: Well, I'm developing an application for personal use, for me this is about learning and seeing what's possible. From what I've seen in the spring security code, the cookie seems to be just a random byte-sequence that is beeing matched. I don't need this piece of software, I'd just like to see this working (which is - in my opinion - enough motivation for many people that write software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion evercookie isn't good choice. It is generating tremendous number of http requests. It has killed my browser. Your users will be fourious about it.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html

Comment: Thanks for this tip volkerjaan!